# Casting u_int32 to char

Tags: c, pointers, casting

The following code

```
u_int32 *data_out
data_out = malloc(4  * sizeof(uint32_t));
//connection_fd is a socket
n = write(connection_fd, data_out[0], strlen(data_out[0]));
```

produces the following error:

Array.c:261: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/string.h:399: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'uint32_t'

I tried the following as well, but still a warning is the result:

```
n = write(connection_fd, (char) data_out[0], strlen((char) data_out[0]));
n = write(connection_fd, (char*) data_out[0], strlen((char*) data_out[0]));
```

Thanks for any insights :),
Patrick

Comment: The million dollar question: *what are you trying to do?*

Comment: Why you're using `strlen()` for something that is certainly not a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are using strlen to write int?
Maybe use:

```
n = write(connection_fd, &(data_out[0]), sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Comment: That better be `data_out`, not `data_out[0]`, since this is being pulled by address for the `write` call.

Comment: You are right, but i think he want to point for first array element, so maybe better `$(data_out[0])` to explicit that I mean first element

Comment: I'm preferential to `(data + n)` for pointer arithmetic, but everyone has their preferences too. This works, and seems to have solved the OP's problem. gj.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Following your warning message

1st case: `strlen()` is expecting a `const char *`

2nd case : converting to `char` only wont work and even if you do `char*` you will get  warning because , `strlen()` works on `\0` null terminated string to give the length of the string but `data_out[i]` is `int` so the problem

here you are passing `int` as a pointer to `char` that's why the warning :

```
passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

As I am seeing everything is clear in the message , Why didn't you understand.

```
    Array.c:261: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer     
from integer without a cast /usr/include/string.h:399: note: expected 
'const char *' but argument is of type 'uint32_t'
```

for `write()` there is problem too.

`(char*)data_out` or `(char*)&data_out[0]` as in 2nd argument instead what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the compiler has already told you what's wrong with the code.

> strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Means: you are trying to show an integer into a pointer variable without a cast.

> expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'uint32_t'

Means: the function wanted a const char *pointer* but you gave it an uint32_t *variable instance*.